# different between catch block version C#6 and older versions

Tags: c#, try-catch, c#-6.0, catch-block

In C# 6 you can make this code:

```
try  { }
catch (Exception e) when (e is NullReferenceException) { }
catch (Exception e) when (e is UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
```

But what's the different between code above and the older C# code below?

```
try  { }
catch (NullReferenceExceptione e) { }
catch (UnauthorizedAccessExceptione e) { }
```

For me looks the older version the shortest and best to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But what's the different between code above and the older C# code below?

`e` will be of type `Exception` in the body of the catch, rather than being of the derived type.

> For me looks the older version the shortest and best to use.

Then use that.

---

The whole point of the `when` keyword here is that it allows you to write arbitrary boolean expressions to determine if you have a match, instead of *only* being able to filter expressions based on whether the expression is a given derived type.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, not much other than the typing of `e` in the catch.

The keyword is more designed for trivial true / false checks like:

```
try 
{
  // Do stuff
} 
catch (Exception e) when (
  (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
  || (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)) {
  // Swallow
}
```

([Code Source](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/07/17/c-6-exception-filters-will-improve-your-home-life/))